# HTML & CSS displays wrong on Retina 2800x2000

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, cross-browser, retina

I have a problem displaying my website on large retina displays. On desktop and mobile it goes well, but on MacBook retina screen it looks huge and doesn't fit into browser. Is there a way to make the .container look the same width and height and float top left on all devices and all screens ()?

`<body> <div class="container"> <nav> </nav> </div> </body>`

here is the website: [www.pctutorials.16mb.com](http://www.pctutorials.16mb.com)

Here is the code:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:none;
}

p {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: normal;
    color: white;
}

.container {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 1080px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat top left;
    background-size: 2000px 1080px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide us the basic structure of your HTML code too?

Comment: <body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>

here is the website: www.pctutorials.16mb.com

Comment: Can you edit the question and add relevant html code in the question itself?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you set `.container` fixed values of `width` and `height`. Same goes for `nav` element.

*This* is why your webpage doesn't fit on a MacBook (and pretty much all the other laptops, *retina or not*, too).

To fix this, I'd start with:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
```

and

```
nav {
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
```

Then, you'd need to play with is `.nav-menu` which might be cut off on smaller screens. Sadly, there's no way you can fix this without playing with media queries a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for that.  played with @media queries for a bit, but didn't get any decent result. It still kept displaying awful.